# Hibernate ignores initialValue for sequence generator

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to have a unique ID across all tables in my database that is starting with an offset, let's say 1000. The IDs below that offset are reserved for special records that are referenced by constants in the Java code. In other words, the first record that is persisted in any table I would expect to have ID 1000, the next one 1001 etc.

I followed the instructions in the Hibernate documentation and various posts and these are the annotations I'm using:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_sequence", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 10)
private long id;
```

Unfortunately Hibernate completely ignores the initialValue setting. It generates the following SQL code:

```
create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint)
insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
```

I also had a try with the TABLE strategy which also does not work. The ID starts with 1.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@TableGenerator(name = "my_sequence", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 10)
private long id;
```

By the way, this does work with EclipseLink JPA provider. My Hibernate version is 5.2.7 and I am going through the JPA API. I am using MySQL.

Has anybody experienced this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator name must be included in the @GeneratedValue annotation, such as:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "my_sequence")    
@TableGenerator(
  name = "my_sequence",
  table = "id_gen",
  pkColumnName = "gen_name",
  valueColumnName = "gen_val",
  initialValue = 1000,
  allocationSize = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed some attributes on both of the strategies:

**Sequence**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_sequence", sequenceName= "dbsequence"
                   initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 10)
private long id;
```

**Table**

Id generation table should have two columns. The first column is a String type used to identify the particular generator sequence. It is the primary key for all the generators in the table. The Second column is an integer type that stores the actual id sequence that is being generated. The value stored in this column is the last identifier that was allocated in the sequence.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@TableGenerator(name = "my_sequence"
              , table = "id_gen"
              , pkColumnName = "gen_name"
              , valueColumnName = "gen_val"
              , initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 10)
private long id;
```

The table strategy is obviously more portable so consider that when you will make a choice.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Hibernate keeps ignoring the annotation parameters such as the table name or initial value: "create table hibernate_sequences". These parameters are optional after all.

Answer (score 0):

you should name your @sequencegenerator then add the same name to @generatedvalue

you need also to create-drop your table (in application.properties) or your application is going to run the table with old sequence parameters

```
`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE , name="my_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_sequence",sequenceName="my_sequence", initialValue = 1000,allocationSize = 10)
 private long id;`
```